# Is there any equivalent of parse line "," in Red?

Tags: rebol, red

In Rebol you could parse a line with

```
parse line ",.#;"
```

In Red, is there an equivalent ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next to that is split, although just a mezzanine wrapper for parse with a special rule. You can use it with multiple delimiters like that

```
split line charset ",.#;"
```

Comment: It works but I don't understand why and I rather agree with @rebolek it should have worked without to-bitset ;)

Comment: @user310291 Why should a STRING! not indicate a longer splitting sequence?  `split "a::b::c" "::"` returning `[a b c]` seems right to me.  If you want SPLIT to model its argument as a collection of characters, the caller should be the one figuring out how to supply it as a collection.

Answer (score 2):

Red moved this functionality to `split`, but I see that it doesn’t work with multiple delimiters as in your case. I will report it as bug.

UPDATE: See https://github.com/red/red/issues/3095